# Use "revalidateTag" to re-validate a RSC/data from a database?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am currently going through everything from the new Nextjs 13.4 update. But I couldn't find any information about using "revalidateTag" with the DB in the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidateTag) they only give an example with a fetch request. I'm making a simple Todo App and when I update a task I have to re-validate `/tasks`, `/tasks/1` and `/tasks/1/edit` routes with "revalidatePath". It does work but sometimes you have to refresh to see the changes

"src/app/tasks"

```
export default async function TaskEditPage({ params }: TaskPageProps) {
    async function editTask(formData: FormData) {
        "use server";

        // validatig data

        await kysely
            .updateTable("task")
            .set({
                title: data.title,
                description: data.description,
                priority: data.priority,
                finished_at: data.finished_at,
            })
            .where("id", "=", Number(params.id))
            .execute();

        revalidatePath(`/ssr/tasks/${params.id}/edit`);
        revalidatePath(`/ssr/tasks/${params.id}`);
        revalidatePath(`/ssr/tasks`);
        redirect(`/ssr/task/${params.id}`);
    }

    // returning tsx
}
```

My question is how to a tag to database call or is there another solution to this problem? If I don't re validate the route the page doesn't update but the database does and re validating every route where i use updated data kinda sucks. the `export const revalidate = 60; // revalidate this page every 60 seconds` is a option.

Comment: Did you found how to revalidate a page data? I am also having this issue. I tried to use revalidatePath without success.